# In a linux based OS disable the keyboard input to a specific application?

Tags: linux, input, keyboard, raspberry-pi

In a linux (more specifically Raspbian/Debian for the Raspberry Pi) is it possible to disable the keyboard input to a specific application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close the input file descriptor - using C it's simply (unless any other descriptors are open for input which would be unlikely) descriptor zero.

```
close(0);
```

Subsequent to closing this descriptor Any reads will fail with errno set to `EBADF` (bad file descriptor).

Comment: I find more readable to code the same as `close(STDIN_FILENO);` using the standard `STDIN_FILENO` (defined as 0). And one could also `open("/dev/null", O_RDONLY);` after that so that file descriptor 0 remains used...